# Slicing a MTLTexture of type - 2DArray in Swift environment

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metal-performance-shaders

Consider a `MTLTexture` of type `2DArray` having some number of slices. To calculate histogram of a specific slice of this texture, **how to pass only the reference of a single slice of texture to MPSImageHistogram shader?**

**In general, How to slice a texture in swift environment?** `Texture.makeTextureview()` is not the preferred way because it creates a new texture consuming more memory and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeTextureView` doesn't create a new texture, even though it returns `MTLTexture`. It creates a texture view. Let me explain.

You can think of a texture as a header and one or more blobs of data. Header tells API and GPU how to interpret the blobs of data. Header is pretty small, blobs can be large.

Now, think of a texture view like a new header, but it references blobs of another texture and doesn't have its own blobs, meaning it doesn't copy blobs of a texture you are "viewing" into. This is a cheap way to reinterpret data of an existing texture. For example, you would use texture view when you only need one slice of a texture array or just one face of a cubemap, or if you want to view sRGB texture as linear or vice versa.

Comment: Texture view is still a Swift object, yes, and it will take up some memory, but if you are running into problems where these API objects themselves are taking up too much memory, you probably need to restructure something in your app.

Comment: Creating each texture with single slice would help? 
Obviously it will add up memory initially but I can reuse them, and directly send to MPSImageHistogram shader (without requirement of slicing).

Comment: What I mean is, if you have a 2D array of textures already, copying the textures around just to get a one-slice texture is wasteful. Instead, if you need a "simple" 2D one slice texture, you can create a view for the specific 2D array slice and it isn't going to waste a lot of memory, because texture view doesn't copy the texture data, it just creates a different header (or descriptor) for the data.